# change bootstrap carousel id

Tags: jquery, navigation, clone, bootstrap-carousel

i have carousel with `width=300px` and `height=300px`
I wanted to display modal and clone all carousel dom elements to view it larger
every thing is copied as i wanted.
but on clicking next prev buttons the older carousel moves not the one in modal
I also changed `id` of new carousel and `href` inside new carousel but still new carousel is not scrolling on clicking 'next/prev or indicators'

```
$('#oldCarousel .item img').click(function(){
    var carousel = $(this).parents('#oldCarousel');
    carousel.attr('id','NewCarousel');
    carousel.find('a[href="#oldCarousel"]').attr('href','#NewCarousel');
    $('#myModal .modal-dialog').html(carousel.clone());
    //$('#myModal .modal-content,#myModal .item,#myModal .modal-dialog').css({'width':'95%','height':'95%','max-height':'95%'});
    $('#myModal .modal-dialog').css('padding','0px');
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    $('#NewCarousel').carousel().carousel(0);
});
```

this is jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/yo0gxtd9/

Comment: Could you possibly add a `fiddle` and post some html?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yo0gxtd9/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make your carousel bigger, isn't it better to adjust `width` and `height` using for example some CSS class?

JS:

```
var elements = $("#oldCarousel").add("#oldCarousel .item img");

$('#oldCarousel .item img').click(function(){
    elements.toggleClass("fullscreen");
});
```

CSS:

```
   .fullscreen {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    img.fullscreen {
      min-width: 100vw;
      min-height: 100vh;
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
    }
```

Please check the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/yo0gxtd9/3/

Comment: this is not working for me, as my carousel is displayed at centered of page even i tried fullscreen=absolute but not gets fit showing inside parent and broken

Comment: What do you mean by fullscreen=absolute? I'm not copying all the contents to another carousel - in my opinion it would be a very bad approach. Please, try updated version and tell me what is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Below are few issue I've noted and providing this solution here:

- `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` - You need to stop the event bubbling to its parent when you click on an image, so that the `carousel` is not rolled when you click on `image`
- `carousel.clone()` - You were changing `carousel` attributes, which effected original one and then while inserting `html` you where using `clone`. This resulted both the `carousel` being getting same `attributes/id`. So you need to clone`first and then change the`attribute values`.

Below is the updated version of your code.

```
$('#oldCarousel .item img').click(function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation(); //stops event being propagated to its parent
    var carousel = $(this).parents('#oldCarousel').clone(); //clone it and then change attributes
    carousel.attr('id','NewCarousel');
    carousel.find('a[href="#oldCarousel"]').attr('href','#NewCarousel');
    $('#myModal .modal-dialog').html(carousel); //attach the cloned version
    $('#myModal .modal-dialog').css('padding','0px');
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    $('#NewCarousel').carousel().carousel(0);
});
```

**[Here's the Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/yo0gxtd9/5/)**